# Kafka schema registry RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 401

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to read data from a kafka avro topic using the avro schema from the confluent client registry. I am using `io.confluent` library version `5.4.1`.
This is the entry in the gradle file

```
    compile (group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-avro-serializer', version: '5.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.avro', module: 'avro'
    }
```

I receive the following error.

```
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 401
```

```
public PCollection<KV<String, GenericRecord>> apply(Pipeline p) {
       ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider<GenericRecord> valDeserializerProvider =
                ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of(params.schemaUrl, "topic-value");

        PCollection<KafkaRecord<String, GenericRecord>> records = p.apply("GetDataFromKafka", KafkaIO.<String, GenericRecord>read()
                .withBootstrapServers(params.apiHost)
                .withTopics("topic")
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(params.getConsumerProps())
                .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withValueDeserializer(valDeserializerProvider)
                .commitOffsetsInFinalize());

        return records.apply("TopicAndDataInput", MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<KafkaRecord<String, GenericRecord>, KV<String, GenericRecord>>() {
            @Override
            public KV<String, GenericRecord> apply(KafkaRecord<String, GenericRecord> input) {
                String topic = input.getTopic();
                GenericRecord data = input.getKV().getValue();
                return KV.of(topic, data);
            }
        }));
    }
```

What am I missing here? Could someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

This is the function to get consumer properties

```
    public Map<String, Object> getConsumerProps() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<> ();

        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("retry.backoff.ms",500);
        props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", 8388608);
        props.put("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO");
        props.put("basic.auth.user.info", "registry_key:secret");
        props.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm","https");
        props.put("security.protocol","SASL_SSL");
            
        props.put("sasl.jaas.config","org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='"+ apiKey +"' password='" + apiSecret +"';");
        props.put("sasl.mechanism","PLAIN");
        return props;
    }
```

Tried also with the following props and still get the same unauthorized error.

```
props.put("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO");
props.put("schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info", "<registry key>:<value>");
props.put("schema.registry.url", schemaUrl);
```

Comment: `Unauthorized; error code: 401` is pretty clear cut. Have you checked the Schema Registry credentials directly using something like like `curl` ?

Comment: curl -s -u <registry_key:secret> GET https://<host_name>.confluent.cloud/subjects returns a valid response.

Comment: Have you imported `ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider` from Apache Beam, and did you mean to do that?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have imported org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider;

Comment: Have you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

I used to have the same issue with libraries `5.3.0`.
I resolved it updating to

```
'org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.2'
'io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:6.2.0'
```

I am using the following props to connect Schema Registry:

```
"schema.registry.url": "<URL>"
"schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO"
"schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info": "<API_KEY>:<API_SECRET>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should add the specific schema registry key and secret as

```
props.put("schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info", "<SCHEMA_REGISTRY_API_KEY>:<SCHEMA_REGISTRY_API_SECRET>");
```

to the properties. (from https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/cp-component/streams-cloud-config.html)

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try it out yet. I will try it out and update whether or works or not. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question with the properties you mentioned and it still throws the same error. Wondering if there is something more than `.withConsumerConfigUpdates ` to pass these properties.